# Opening a swf file in windows services(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service, flash

I am trying to open a .swf file from windows services.I have developed the service in VS 10(C#).Is that possible?If yes,how?I don't want to convert the swf file to exe as it could raise security concerns.

Comment: what do you mean by open? do you want to open the stream and read the file? then it's possible.

Comment: The swf file is a video encoder.I want to use this file in a service so that this encoder gets started automatically whenever I boot my computer.So,by open,I mean that i want to,simply,play the swf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!!!
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110568/Alternative-way-for-Window-services-to-interact-wi
This post gives the perfect code for opening a swf or any .exe file from windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link>>

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5815e676-50b0-47f4-964a-c1bcebfdb9a4/

There are COM wrappers named `axshockwaveflash`

Also follow:

http://www.programmingforums.org/post164816.html

Comment: :Thankyou for your help.This solution didn't work,but you got me started in the right direction.I followed this link:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/69365/.But now I've a new problem:My service gets stopped automatically,saying "Some services get stopped automatically if they are not being used by other programs.I don't get this.Is there a solution for this?

Comment: put try catch block around the code and see from where it is getting exception

Comment: It's not an asp.net exception.This is a alert raised when I try to start my service from services.msc.Should I go back and try the COM wrapper approach?

Comment: When debugging Windows Services startup problems, I usually include something along the lines of `while(!Debugger.IsAttached){Thread.Sleep(500)}` right at the startup routine of the service. That way you can install and start the service comfortably and have it wait until you attach the debugger from Visual Studio.

Comment: What don't you understand?